# Site with Jenkins plugins per Jenkins version

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I need to find plugins for Jenkins 1.609.3. Is anyone aware of a site that shows the mapping between "plugin version" and "Jenkins version"?

Otherwise I'm searching among a myriad of plugins versions....

Comment: The plugins available for your version are in the Plugins section inside Jenkins Manage menu. You are using and older Jenkins version, be careful with the external plugins sources.

Comment: The section you are referring to lists lots of plugins that are compatible with much newer Jenkins versions and warns me accordingly, therefore it's pretty much useless. The plugins I wish to install are among those, and clearly it makes no sense to install them if they are not going to work. I wish Jenkins was, indeed, able to bring me plugins in a version that would work on my installation. Instead of telling me "here it is, but don't bother installing it".

Answer (score 1):

You may still install compatible plugins from the Jenkins repository straight away. However some plugins may require newer version of Jenkins and thus should not work.

If you really need old jenkins and old plugins you may want to try the wayback machine from the internet archive at https://web.archive.org/web/*/jenkins-ci.org

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. If nothing else, I can see when my Jenkins version was released, and date-match it with whatever plugin I need.